# How to wait for a Kotlin coroutine to finish

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I've read dozens of posts, but somehow none of the answers seems to work in my case.

What I want to achieve is is to wait in Fragment for ViewModel to perform operations using Room.

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun getMyData(id: Long): List<Item>
```

In the ViewModel I don't need to return anything, just update my variable with some data from the database. I've tried other approaches here as well, i.e. returning a Deferred

ViewModel:

```
suspend fun updateData(myItem: Item) {
    for (myField in myItem.fields) {
        myField.someOtherField = myDao.getMyData(myField.id)
    }
}
```

I've tried waiting with runBlocking, lifecycleScope.launch, with async.await() but always with the same result. I need to work on an updated item.

Fragment:

```
runBlocking {
    val job = launch{
        viewModel.updateData(myItem)
    }
    job.join()
    doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem(myItem) //this always executes before viewModel.updateData(myItem) even starts
}
```

Comment: Your code should work as is.  Is there some other code involved?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't see anything that could be relevant. Only thing that comes to mind is that the runBlocking block is inside an observer and myItem actually is the value returned from this observer. Could it have some influence?

Comment: What exactly are you using to prove that `doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem` is executing before `viewModel.updateData(myItem)`?

Answer (score 3):

If there is no other code involved then it should run in this order.

```
runBlocking {
    println("run blocking")
    val job = launch {
        delay(1000)
        println("launch new job")
    }
    job.join()
    println("do something")
}
```

This code will print:

```
run blocking
launch new job
do something
```

In your case, I would use `withContext/async` for the `viewModel.updateData` logic.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are not just running the final code *inside the coroutine*?

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.updateData(myItem)
    doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem(myItem)
}
```

That's using coroutines how they are really meant to be used.

Ultimately, though, I wonder if this problem here is in the mutability of your items. Why not return a new set of items instead of trying to mutate the existing ones? Then you'd have something like

```
suspend fun updateData(myItem: Item): Item {
    return myItem.copy(
        fields = myItem.fields.map { field -> myDao.getMyData(field.id) }
    )
}
```

And then you'd pass the updated item to your final function:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val updatedItem = viewModel.updateData(myItem)
    doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem(updatedItem)
}
```

Or just replace `lifecycleScope.launch` with `runBlocking` and it's the same idea:

```
runBlocking {
    val updatedItem = viewModel.updateData(myItem)
    doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem(updatedItem)
}
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't guarantee the order of suspend function executions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean....are you talking about the order of `updateData` and `doSomethingElseWithUpdatedmyItem`? They literally must run in the order they are written there. They are running in the same coroutine. This is different from the original post, where there is a nested `launch` call.